# Csv data is not being parsed correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im inputting some csv data such as `S:1111    S:2222    S:3333    S:4444    S:5555    S:6666    S:7777    S:8888` and im trying to parse the data in a way so that it will be aligned in as `1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888`. But when i try to parse the data, i get something like `1111    2222    3333    4444    5555    6666    7777    8888`.

```js
var spaces = 4;
var csv = 'S:1111    S:2222    S:3333    S:4444    S:5555    S:6666    S:7777    S:8888';
    
var output =
csv.split(' '.repeat(spaces)).map(part => part.substr(2)).join(' '.repeat(spaces));

console.log(output);
```

Does anyone see the reason why i could be getting the output the way i am getting it instead of the way that i want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches your desired output

```js
var spaces = 4;
var csv = 'S:1111    S:2222    S:3333    S:4444    S:5555    S:6666    S:7777    S:8888';

var output =
csv.split(/\s+/).map(part => part.split(':')[1]).join(', ');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex that looks for characters between the `:` and space or end of line then join the matches

```js
const expr =/(?<=\:).+?(?=\s|$)/g;

const str ='S:1111    S:2222    S:3333    S:4444    S:5555    S:6666    S:7777    S:8888'

const res = str.match(expr).join(', ')

console.log(res)
```